# Revamp existing JSF front end with React or Angular

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-redux, web-frontend

I have an application which is built using JSF. I want to revamp it and I am little confused whether I can use my existing REST APIs with some new Front end framework like React or angular.

Also if any one can suggest which one is better and why in terms of flexibility, scalability, security purpose (CSRF etc ).

Comment: Yes you can use your existing REST API, the rest is matter of opinions.

Comment: @penleychan could you please help me pick which one I should go for , I am novice in React as well as Angular. Considering the trending and stable framework which one should I choose,

Comment: @penleychan's comment is about as accurate as you're gonna get. They are pretty similar in terms of what they can do. Angular may be slightly easier for formatting output values, but I love working with JSX. Go with whichever you find easier to use.